# problem in quartz 2D drawing touches began

Tags: iphone, touchesbegan

I have drawn 5 circles in in my app one above the other . But i want to perform different operations when i touch each circle and there is only one touches began where I can perform touches for the entire  view.. can anyone help me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Either process the coordinates of the touch to "grab" a specific circle (you know their coordinates if you have the origins and radii), or put each circle into its own view, and make five subviews/circles of a parent view. Pass the touch down the view chain until the coordinates overlap.

Comment: if i put each circle in a diff view does it take more memory?? and also I know the coordinates ; but how do i perform touches began for that method alone. Since i'm drawing in quartz 2d I cant make it each circle as an object to touch that circle alone?? 

And also i would appreciate if u could clear this doubt also. My circle in a  separate view and when I touch that view it should perform some this else in some othr view. how to pass the coordinates of X and y to another class view

Thanks in advance